# $(E\cup F)' = E' \cup F'$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $E$ and $F$ be subsets of a metric space $X.$ Show that
> $$(E\cup F)' = E' \cup F'$$

I have seen proofs of this problem but what is bothering me is the contradicting nature of two arguments that I have come up with.

I shall denote $D_r(x)$ to mean the deleted neighborhood of $x$ with radius $r.$

> Argument I :
>
> \begin{align}
> x\in(E\cup F)'\\
> \iff D_r(x)\cap(E\cup F)\ne \emptyset,\forall r>0\\
> \iff (D_r(x)\cap E)\cup(D_r(x)\cap F)\ne \emptyset,\forall r>0\\
> \iff D_r(x)\cap E \ne \emptyset \text{ or }D_r(x)\cap F \ne \emptyset, \forall r>0\\
> \iff x\in E' \text{ or }x\in F' \\
> \iff x\in E'\cup F' \\\end{align}

It was all well and good until (for the fun of it) I decided to prove the same using contraposition :

> Argument II :
> \begin{align}
> x\notin(E\cup F)'\\
> \iff \exists r>0 \text{ s.t }D_r(x)\cap(E\cup F) = \emptyset,\\
> \iff \exists r>0 \text{ s.t }(D_r(x)\cap E)\cup(D_r(x)\cap F)= \emptyset\\
> \iff \exists r>0 \text{ s.t }D_r(x)\cap E = \emptyset \text{ and }D_r(x)\cap F = \emptyset\\
> \iff x\notin E' \text{ and }x\notin F' \\
> \iff x\notin E'\cap F' \\\end{align}

Where am I going wrong in the second argument? I feel like I got my negations all wrong but I am not able to find it.

Comment: Does $E'$ denote the closure of $E$?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch $E'$ denote the set of all limit points of $E.$

Comment: https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/10206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning in Argument II is correct up to the second last line. However,
\begin{equation}
x\not\in E' \text{ and } x\not\in F' \iff x \not\in E'\cap F'
\end{equation}
is incorrect. In fact, we have (where $\land$ denotes "and"; $\lor$ denotes "or"; and $\lnot$ denotes "not"):
\begin{split}
x\not\in E' \text{ and } x\not\in F' &\iff \lnot(x\in E')\land \lnot(x\in F') \\
&\iff \lnot (x\in E' \lor x\in F') \qquad \text{(by De Morgan's law)}\\
&\iff \lnot (x \in E'\cup F')  \\
&\iff x \not\in E' \cup F'.
\end{split}

*Remark.* This mistake is not specific to metric spaces, but rather to set theory.